# Loop through a folder of PDF files and append a single PDF to each

Tags: macos, pdf, terminal, pdf-generation

This code just seems to replace the first file, not append file1.pdf to it.
I need the file to append not replace.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=("/Users/a/folder/"*.pdf)
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "${f}"
    "/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py" -o "${f}" "${f}" "/Users/a/folder2/file1.pdf"
done
```

I noticed, if I run the code manually, but use a different name for the first and second parameters, it seems to work. However, I do not know how to change the name of the first parameter without making it a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me your problem has nothing to do with Ruby. As I'm understanding it, you are trying to use the command line on MacOS X El Capitan to merge a PDF file with other PDF files.

If I understood your problem correctly, then you probably should heed the advice of [this weblog](http://gotofritz.net/blog/howto/joining-pdf-files-in-os-x-from-the-command-line/) and use the command `"/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py"` which is available from MacOS X Tiger onwards.

Note that if the file you want to append is in the same directory where all the files are you want to append to, you'll run into problems: the script join.py does not seem to appreciate being given the same file thrice, so place your file elsewhere (the one you want to append to all files).

Try something along the lines of:

`#!/bin/bash
for f in /Absolute/Path/To/The/PDFS/*.pdf;
do /System/Library/Automator/Combine\ PDF\ Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py -o $f $f /Absolute/Path/To/The/File/To/Append; done`

Comment: I actually read that, but it does not show how to loop through a folder. unless I missed it.

Comment: Indeed, as I don't have a Mac on hand to try out things, I only focused on what seemed hardest to me (namely joining PDFs)... It seems that to cycle through files in a folder, something along the lines of `for f in *; do
  echo $f;
done` should work on MacOS X as well as other UNIX systems but I cannot test it.

Comment: With the first two parameters the same, the join.py script does not work for some reason. It saves the over the original file with the appended file, instead of appending it. See what worked below.  Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Well that is strange... I dug up an old MacBook Pro and tried the code I suggested and it works fine for me with the first two parameters identical as long as the third parameter is different...

Comment: Not sure what the difference is. Maybe the version. I'm running OS X 10.11.6

Comment: I think the difference is that my file path has spaces.   "/Users/a/one and two/folder/*.pdf" I tried your code again and it does not work for me

Comment: Just in case, please try to remove the quotes and instead to escape the spaces in the path so that `"/Users/a/one and two"` becomes `/Users/a/one\ and\ two`
It could help (it did on my macbook pro for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=("/Users/a/folder/"*.pdf)
for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "${f}"
    a="${f%.pdf}"
    "/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py" -o "${a}_x.pdf" "${f}" "/Users/a/folder2/file1.pdf"
done
```